# Url.Action() is Sending id as a parameter, which I don't want to send to as a link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have witten a simple jQuery function which looks like this

```
$('#Add').on('click', function () {
   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Salary")',
   $("#Mode").val("Create");
});
```

I am doing both Create/Edit from a Same view action, so the problem is when I wanted to go back from Edit mode to create my jQuery functions add id to link.

Like this...

```
$('#Add').on('click', function () {
      window.location.href = '/Salary/Create/6',
     $("#Mode").val("Create");
});
```

Comment: Because the view you have created was from an ActionResult method that had a parameter `int ID`. You can remove it by using `'@Url.Action("Create", "Salary", new { id = "" })',`

Comment: Not Worked Mr: @stephen Yes i have 'int? ID' in my Action but i dont want to send ,

Comment: Try `new { id = null }`

Comment: Error **cannot assign <null> to anonymous type property**

Comment: try `new { id = (int?) null }`

Comment: Give me 15 min - using `new { id = "" }` should be working.

Comment: Its working thank you,,,,

Comment: You should consider having separate Create and Edit actions, where Create doesn't have an ID.  To keep the code simple, Create simply calls Edit with a null ID.  This makes the *intention* much clearer as you're not calling "create" on an existing item (in an attempt to imply edit that item).